# SharePoint 2013 Library Views

Tags: 2013, list-view, document, library

By default libraries have 3 views across the library header and the others available in the ... drop down. I have managed to 'break' this and now only have one view in the header. Does anyone have any ideas where this is controlled and how I can get back to three view or even change it to four. 
Many thanks, Chris

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 `View Selector Menu` is rendered using the `ClientPivotControl` control (`clienttemplate.js`)

### How to control View Selector Menu in SharePoint 2013

The parameter `SurfacedPivotCount` determines how many view items are displayed in List View header, it is declared in `ClientPivotControl` control:

```
ClientPivotControl.prototype = { 
    SurfacedPivotCount: 3
    //...
};
```

The following script demonstrates how to override standard behavior in order to display 6 view menu items:

```
if (typeof ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount !== "undefined") {
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 6;
}
```

**How to apply changes**

1. Open View page in edit mode
2. Insert `Script Editor` web part on the page
3. Insert the provided code by enclosing it using `script` tag

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but try:

1. Browse to your list
2. Go go List-->List Settings
3. Click on "Advanced Settings"
4. Scoll down, there is a quick edit option to switch on or off

and test this link 
[Ghosting, Unghosting, Customized, and Uncustomized](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=87#.VDZHIvl_u1c)

- Ghosted = Un-Customized, The asp.net parser renders the
  page.
- Unghosted = Customized, Controlled by the SafeMode
  parser.
- Reghosting = Changing from Customized to
  Un-Customized